# Complement learning

Tags: clustering

First off, complement learning is a term I made up, not sure if it really exists.

Given that the ground truth consists of 2 classes: class 1, class 2, and also two observed sets: oset 1, oset 2, such that:

- oset 1 naturally contains samples from class 1 AND class 2, with (in my case) unknown priors
- oset 2 contains samples of class 1

Summarized, I do not have class labels, but only observation labels, can I use this to train a model to classify between both classes (to find the ground truth separation between class 1 and class 2)?

I called this complement learning, because you try to find the complement between oset 2, given that oset 1 is the universe.

Note: this differs from outlier-detection and anomaly detection, since you have 'so to speak', an idea of what the non-outlier and non-anomalous data is (in the form of oset 2). Moreover, the samples of class 2 may not show typical outlier behavior.

Is there a better approach than clustering both osets and determining the clusters of oset 1 with little/no overlap with the clusters of oset 2.

Is there a machine learning variant which tackles this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Train a one-class classifier on each set, and evaluate it on the other.

There are a number of methods such as one-class SVMs that are trained on good data only.

Comment: Would a Gaussian Mixture Model be an example of such a one-class classifier? This sounds very simple and reasonable, GREAT!

Comment: Not without extensions, because it is not a classifier... but yes, you could train a GMM on each of the sets, and check if the other set has an unusual amount of "outliers" with respect to this model.

Comment: Well, you can train a GMM by splitting the oset2 in 3 parts, one to initialized the GMM, one to select the optimal parameters (variances and probability threshold) and one to check which fraction of it is indeed above the threshold. Than you can use this threshold-based classifier to separate oset1. (If that makes sense)

Comment: @has-quit-anony-mousse sad to read your profile text, still happy with your answer!